# Flutter using a changenotifier with named routes

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I've followed some online tutorials and managed to implement ChangeNotifier when the app has a single route however none of these explain how to implement this when the app has more than one route (screen) which is rather the point!

I made an attempt to figure this out myself but when the app runs in the emulator I get a blank screen.

```dart
/* main.dart */

import 'dart:collection'; // used in test.dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'; // used in test.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Person extends ChangeNotifier {
  Person({this.firstName});
  String firstName = '';
  void updateName(String n) {
    this.firstName = n;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    Provider(
      create: (_) => Person(firstName: 'Mark'),
      child: MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => HomeRoute(),
          '/second': (context) => SecondRoute(),
          '/third': (context) => ThirdRoute(),
        },
      ),
    )
  );
}

class HomeRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(Provider.of<Person>(context).firstName),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.redAccent),
          iconSize: 70.0,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/second");
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Second Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(Provider.of<Person>(context).firstName),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThirdRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Third Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Third Route'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The project builds and runs with no error messages which has stumped me.

Any thoughts?

> Code developed in FlutLab

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine. maybe `flutter clean` and removing app entirely and running it again would help?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Must be a bug in FlutLab.